# Why is the Keychain more secure than encrypted data saved in a file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Why is the Keychain more secure than encrypted data that is saved as a file in the iOS application's Document's directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically data is encrypted with a symmetric encryption algorithm such as AES and the encryption key is saved in the keychain. The data can be placed in any file location, the protection is via the encryption algorithm and the secret key.

The keychain stores the keys (and other small data) encrypted and restricts access to that data. Additionally in recent iPhones (5S and later) the keychain is in a separate processor, the Secure Enclave which additionally restricts access. There is no more secure way to store keys in iOS.

Comment: I have been reading numerous articles and keychain isn't the most secure way to store keys in iOS.

First, if the user does not password protect the device, there is no encryption performed when stored in the keychain.

Second, if the phone is jail broken, the concept of sand boxing is no longer true.  Combined that with once the user unlocks the device, the decryption key is generated.  So potentially harmful application can view what is stored in your application's keychain.

I am currently looking for a secure way to store a key on the device as well.

Comment: How can you say "keychain isn't the most secure way to store keys" when you can not provide a better solution? If the user is not interested in security, no passcode and/or jailbreaks that is the user's choice and jailbreaking does not defeat the keychain security. Tying to protect from the device owner is futile, by default the owner has full access. If you want to protect data from the user you need DRM and that usually requires a DRM server.

Comment: Right, so if someone wanted to do malicious, the hacker will use an rooted device and download your app.  If they have access to other user's key or even worse; if the developer uses a master key for all of the users, the hacker can spoof any user and gain access.

I think the right path would have to be storing the key on a remote server over SSL and the user must login to gain access to the encrypted data on the iPhone storage.  Assuming that the developer is using a separate SQLCipher.

Of course, there is a balance between security and convenience.

Comment: Again, I am still searching for the right way to approach this.  If one has to think about HIPAA/PII, you have to consider all possibilities of penetration tests and the best interest for the patients and healthcare providers.

Comment: What does downloading the app accomplish? So we move from storing the key on the device to the server which is a different question. That is potentially more secure but just moves the problem to authentication the device to the server. It also just moves accessing the key to attacking the server and where the attacker will have access to all the keys.

Comment: This statement is not accurate, "the keychain is in a separate processor, the Secure Enclave". The Keychain is NOT stored within the Secure Enclave, as per Apple's documentation: "The meta-data key is protected by the Secure Enclave, but is cached in the application processor to allow fast queries of the keychain. The Keychain is implemented as a SQLite database, stored on the file system."

Answer (score 4):

[Apple's Documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/keychain-data-protection-overview-secb0694df1a/web) covers this topic pretty well. Contrary to what others have said, the Keychain is NOT stored within the [Secure Enclave](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave).

> Keychain metadata (all attributes other than kSecValue) is encrypted with the metadata key to speed searches while the secret value (kSecValueData) is encrypted with the secret-key. The meta-data key is protected by the Secure Enclave, but is cached in the application processor to allow fast queries of the keychain. The secret key always requires a roundtrip through the Secure Enclave.
>
> The Keychain is implemented as a SQLite database, stored on the file system.

This means that though both the Keychain and the Documents folder are stored on disk, the Keychain is more secure because it requires an encryption key that is stored on separate hardware (the Secure Enclave) and that encryption key is not accessible through software.

As of this post, almost seven years after its release, sensitive data has never been exfiltrated from within the Secure Enclave.

Answer (score 2):

Document Folder can be accessed by using iExplorer and other third party apps.

Actually key chain is used for only small piece of data as per apple recommendation.

Most mobile applications must interact with Web services that require authentication. Services usually require authentication to provide personalized content (such as social networks) or to limit access to sensitive information (such as corporate data). Most commonly, the authentication requires a username and a password. Most iOS apps store these credentials in the Keychain — a password management system provided by Apple for iPhone and iPad apps to securely store small pieces of sensitive information such as usernames, passwords, tokens, certificates, private keys for asymmetric encryption, and secret keys for symmetric encryption.

This article will present the information necessary for companies to protect access to their corporate resources when those credentials are stored in the iOS Keychain, and for security-conscious individuals to protect their personal passwords stored in the Keychain.

There are a number of conditions that impact the security of the data an app stores in the Keychain:

the presence and strength of a passcode on the device
the access restrictions assigned to the app’s Keychain items
whether the device is jailbroken
the chipset used in the device

Answer (score 0):

Hi maya this link helps you how keychain is secured 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TPXREF10

Comment: Try to avoid off-site stuff. At least put the gist of that resource into your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Keychain data can also be encrypted in a similar way as the data in Document Directory. The difference that keychain does not hold large amount of data.

Document Directory makes the data insecure as it can be easily accessible via method swizzling and encrypted can be broken. The data in the keychain removes this drawback and with encryption, provides better security to the data.